# Sometimes Notifications don’t appear

Tags: notifications

I have found out that sometimes I get text message notifications but sometimes I don’t. This is rather frustrating because I have been sent a text 30 mins before and I didn’t realise this until I physically checked the messages, only to see that I have actually gotten a text and not been notified. Sometimes I do get the notifications, everything is switched on and I am not in Do Not Disturb mode. Is this a hardware issue or could it be a buggy update?

IOS 14.2

Answer (score 1):

It is a [widely](https://www.theverge.com/2020/12/11/22169881/apple-iphone-ios-14-text-messages-no-notifications-bug) [reported](https://9to5mac.com/2020/12/11/ios-14-messages-notifications-iphone/) bug in iOS 14.2. It is not a hardware issue.

Right now there doesn't seem much that can be done about it than wait for Apple to release an update with a fix.